# Clone and rename a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a component that is used often and for many porpuses - `<Box />`.

I'd like to rename it to declare it's functional meaning in the code, something along these lines:

```
import Box from '../reusable-components/Box'

const Wrapper = Box
const Card = Box
const TopSection = Box

// Or like this?
// const [Wrapper, Card, TopSection] = cloneComponent(Box)

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <TopSection style={{display: 'flex'}}>
        <Card>Item A</Card>
        <Card>Item B</Card>
        <Card>Item C</Card>
      </TopSection>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

Comment: why can't you use it as `<Box><Box style={{display: 'flex'}}></Box></Box>`?

Comment: Okay, yes that works?

Comment: @JonasWilms Heh, I didn't realize I did something legit. Thanks.

Comment: @JuniusL I want to rename the component to convey it's purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a react component, there is no point "cloning" it. Since When you use it in , it will create a new instance. In fact I am not clear why you need to rename it at all, but here is how you can do it

```
import Wrapper from '../reusable-components/Box'
import Card from '../reusable-components/Box'
import TopSection from '../reusable-components/Box'
//Or
 const [Wrapper, Card, TopSection] = [Box,Box,Box]

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <TopSection style={{display: 'flex'}}>
        <Card>Item A</Card>
        <Card>Item B</Card>
        <Card>Item C</Card>
      </TopSection>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

Comment: Me neither, I am exapnding on what the OP wanted
 // const [Wrapper, Card, TopSection] = cloneComponent(Box)